# > Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11

Я пытаюсь закомпилить свой код в *intellij idea* и у меня выбивается вот эта ошибка:

```
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 11' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

Я уже добавил переменную `JAVA_HOME`, установил *JRE 1.8*, но все равно ничего не получается.
Уже половину интернета перерыл, но не могу понять, что мне сделать что бы программа запускалась с помощью этого jdk 8, ибо код на нем написан.
Я видел похожую проблему [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995886/gradle-could-not-target-platform-java-se-8-using-tool-chain-jdk-7-1-7), перепробовал все из той темы, но ошибка остается.

Пожалуйста, помогите. Я начинающий программист и с ума схожу тут из-за этой ошибки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В **Gradle**, наверное как и в **Maven**, при подключении зависимостей *слетает версия Java* по нескольким пунктам

`File -> Project Structure -> Project Language Level` - посмотри там версию Java.

`File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler Project Bytecode Version` - там посмотреть версию байткода. Нужно указать **явно** 8ую версию, а не "**Same as language level**"

Answer (score 1):

Правильно интерпретируйте ошибку, требуется Java SE 11.

Настройте `JAVA_HOME` на JDK 11 версии.

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно проверить тут:

```
File -> Settings ->  Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM
```

Выбрать корректную версию.